# Convert array of audio bytes to opus codec

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav, pyaudio, opus

I have a program that uses PyAudio to listen to the computer's audio stream from Stereo Mixer and outputs an array of bytes. I found a lot of information on the Internet on how to convert array of audio bytes to .wav codec using the wave library. But I need to save an array of bytes in an opus codec, and I would like to know if there is a library or a function out of the box python to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is possible to do with ffmpeg and libopus. You could explore a few of the python bindings for these two libraries and see how it goes.

A python binding for ffmpeg is provided by the ffmpeg-python package [here](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/), while a python binding for libopus is provided by the opuslib package [here](https://pypi.org/project/opuslib/).

Command line [`opusenc`](https://opus-codec.org/release/dev/2018/09/18/opus-tools-0_2.html) could also be used with [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) to send/receive audio streams:

```
$ opusenc

Usage: opusenc [options] input_file output_file.opus

opusenc reads audio data in Wave, AIFF, FLAC, Ogg/FLAC, or raw PCM format
and encodes it into an Ogg Opus stream. If the input file is "-" audio data
is read from stdin. Likewise, if the output file is "-" the Ogg Opus stream
is written to stdout.
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging on the Internet, I found a solution. There is a pyogg library that encodes an array of audio bytes into an opus codec. Here is their documentation: *https://pyogg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html*. But, first I installed through *pip install pyogg*, but for some reason some files that are in the documentation did not install, so I found the git of their project and downloaded the files from there - *https://github.com/TeamPyOgg/PyOgg/tree/master/pyogg* .
Below is the code for converting an array of audio bytes to an ogg codec(the code is taken from the documentation):

```
filename = "result"

# Create a OpusBufferedEncoder
opus_buffered_encoder = pyogg.OpusBufferedEncoder()
opus_buffered_encoder.set_application("audio")
opus_buffered_encoder.set_sampling_frequency(48000)
opus_buffered_encoder.set_channels(2)
opus_buffered_encoder.set_frame_size(20)  # milliseconds

# Create an OggOpusWriter
output_filename = filename + ".ogg"
print("Writing OggOpus file to '{:s}'".format(output_filename))
ogg_opus_writer = pyogg.OggOpusWriter(
        output_filename,
        opus_buffered_encoder
)

# Encode the PCM data
ogg_opus_writer.write(
        memoryview(bytearray(b''.join(YOUR_AUDIO_BYTES_ARRAY)))
)

# We've finished writing the file
ogg_opus_writer.close()
```